# What value can I test against to check a variable for a possible unchecked checkbox value

Tags: c#, html, forms, checkbox

I have some error correcting code, and I wanted to test to make sure that a variable assigned by "Request.Form["checkbox"]" is either the value given when it is checked (let's say "ticked") or whatever the value would be if it was unchecked.

I declare the variable as an empty string before I try to assign it a value with Request.Form

I have tried the following:

```
if(IsGangMember != "ticked" || IsGangMember != "")
    {
        errorMessage = "The \"Search For Street Gang Member\" field contains an invalid value.";
    }
```

And this:

```
if(IsGangMember != "ticked" || IsGangMember != null)
    {
        errorMessage = "The \"Search For Street Gang Member\" field contains an invalid value.";
    }
```

And this:

```
if(IsGangMember != "ticked" || IsGangMember.IsEmpty())
    {
        errorMessage = "The \"Search For Street Gang Member\" field contains an invalid value.";
    }
```

I have also tried printing the value to the screen (if box is unchecked) to see it and it is, of course, empty, so I don't see how the value could be anything other than an empty string or null.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

UPDATE:

Okay, all the solutions given make perfect sense but when unchecked, the error message still gets set.

This is literally all I am doing with it:

```
var IsGangMember = "";
```

Then:

```
IsGangMember = Request.Form["sIsGangMember"];
```

(sIsGangMember is the name of the input checkbox field)
Then:

```
if(IsGangMember != "ticked" || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(IsGangMember))
{
    errorMessage = "The \"Search For Street Gang Member\" field contains an invalid value.";
}
```

When left unchecked, the errorMessage still gets assigned. :( Why?

Comment: Why are you not trying to access Checkbox using its "ID"?

Comment: What is the declaration of of IsGangMember ?

Comment: @Praveen Because forms look for name on post...  Anyway it doesn't matter the ID and name are syntactically identical.

Comment: @Milind Thakkar it is declared initially as var IsGangMember = "";

Comment: I think this `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(IsGangMember)` should be other way round `String.IsNullOrEmpty(IsGangMember)`. Also debug your code - breakpoint

Comment: it shouldn't be the other way around because I am testing to see if the checkbox contains values that I would expect it to have, but like the other tests for null or empty string, it still enters the if branch as though some value other than null, empty string or the "ticked" value is assigned to IsGangMember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(IsGangMember))
{
   //test for other values
}
else
{
   //String is empty
}
```

Think should be the other way round

```
if(IsGangMember != "ticked" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(IsGangMember))
{
    errorMessage = "The \"Search For Street Gang Member\" field contains an invalid value.";
}
```

Comment: it shouldn't be the other way around because I am testing to see if the checkbox contains values that I would expect it to have, but like the other tests for null or empty string, it still enters the if branch as though some value other than null, empty string or the "ticked" value is assigned to IsGangMember.

Comment: You are using `||` which is `OR`. So if one of them is true, it would branch in. Spell out how you want the condition checked

Comment: XD

FACEPALM!

It is obvious.... I need "&&" not "||" pshh

How did I not catch this sooner....

Of course it's gonna always be one "or" the other :S

I need sleep...

Comment: Also thnx for teaching me the String.IsNullOrEmpty method.  Didn't know that was there.

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox is not checked it will not be available in Request.Form collection. If checked it will be in the collection with key "checkbox" and value "on".

So you can easyly check it by

```
Request.Form["checkbox"] != null
```

Comment: Then shouldn't the variable i assigned previously to an empty string still be an empty string? I literally need to check the value assigned to the variable.

Comment: @VoidKing Yes you are right. Then you could check it by String.IsNullOrEmpty as "codingbiz" suggested.

Answer (score 0):

XD

FACEPALM!

It is obvious....  I need "&&" not "||"  pshh

How did I not catch this sooner....

Of course it's gonna always be one "or" the other :S

I need sleep...